# Codeigniter pagination create_link() display blank on view page

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Codeigniter pagination `create_link()` display blank on view page..

When I echo pagination `create_link` from controller function it displays perfectly but when I try to echo it on view page it shows blank.

Thanks.

//Below is my code controller code

```
    $row=$this->city_model->city_list();
    //pagination start here
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/edu/index.php/admin/city/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = count($row);
    $config['per_page'] = 10; 
    $config['num_links']=20;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $row=$this->city_model->city_listing($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
    //pagination end here

    //This will generate data into table format
    //$row=$this->city_model->city_list();
    $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table class="data display datatable">' );
    $this->table->set_heading('City Name','State', 'Edit', 'Delete');   
    $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
    foreach($row as $r)
    {
         $edit  = anchor('javascript:void(0)','Edit','id="overlay_dialog"');    
         $del  = anchor('/admin/city/deleteCity/'.$r->city_id ,'Delete');
         $this->table->add_row($r->city_name,$r->stateName,$edit,$del);
    }
    $data['city_table']=$this->table->generate();

     echo $this->pagination->create_links();//pagnigation links work here

    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/leftmenu');
    $this->load->view('admin/city',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');
```

//this is my view code

```
echo $city_table; 
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: post code of controller and view

Comment: Are you sure you are echoing it right? (open `PHP` tags) `<?=$this->pagination->create_links()?>` or `<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>` also take a look at this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/) I am sure you are going to rock the pagination library after watching.

Comment: thanks for reply.echoing it in right manner to my knowlege.. kyslik

Comment: still not working? (answer below is kind of right).

Comment: I don't know the reason, but loading a view and echoing pagination links don't work together in the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You should set pagination links variable in your controller:

```
$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

and output it somewhere in your view:

```
<?php echo $links; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nevermind.. it working like this.. but i still don't understand why its not showing anything if i am trying to echo create link direct on view page..

Answer (score 0):

In controller you have to do all pagination code from here [PaginationLink](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html). and when it work, you have to paste below code in your view. It will create pagination links.

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links() ?>
```

Comment: Please provide some more detail and explanation with your code.